# Checkbox Selected Value in Event Handler

Tags: reactjs

I have a checkbox event handler to update the selected checkbox value state. But now the checkedCampusItems is undefine. Please advise! Thanks.

```
class CampusChk extends React.Component {
state = {checkedCampusItems: [] };
//event handler
handleCampusChkChange=(id,name,value, checked)=> { 
  // current array of options
  const checkedCampusItems = this.state.checkedCampusItems;
  let index;
  // check if the check box is checked or unchecked
  if (checked) {
    //add the name value of the checkbox to arrary
    checkedCampusItems.push(value);
  } else {
    // or remove the value from the unchecked checkbox from the array
    index = checkedCampusItems.indexOf(value);
    checkedCampusItems.splice(index, 1);
  }
  // update the state with the new array of options
  this.setState({checkedCampusItems: checkedCampusItems });
}

render(){
 return (
  <div>
   {campusData.map(item =>
      <label>{item.name}
   <input type="checkbox"  key={item.id} {...item} label={item.name} onChange={this.handleCampusChkChange} /> 
          </label>
  )
   }
   </div>   
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing the arguments to `handleCampusChkChange`

```
onChange={() => handleCampusChkChange(item.id, item.name, item.value, item.check)}
```

Comment: (event) => this.handleCampusChkChange(item.id,item.name,item.value, event.target.checked)